# Drop Down in iphone like uploaded Image

Tags: iphone, ios5, dropdownlistfor

[image]

How to create this type of DropDown in iphone like uploaded image..

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're trying to do.

If you write a question, make sure :
- the question is clear, cannot be mistaken and specifies an actual problem you have

- the question isn't a request for people to write you a piece of code. try yourself first, try reading about your subject. 
Ask StackOverflow if you have questions you cannot figure out.

Comment: actually this is a website in joomla..and i have create app in iphone..so this type of data i have show in iphone..give me solution plz...

Comment: If you cannot even figure out that that takes a UITableViewController, then there is no way you went anywhere near Apple's documentation. (it literally tells you how to do this)

Comment: **Just keep in mind** when you ask question on SO, have you tried anything before asking to other?, okay then post the code here,and tell where you getting stuck or where you need help, I am pretty sure you will get more help from SO community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a view that contain a uitableview and add it to the self.view .
Or you can use **UIPicker** this component is work as a A list